# prove $S = \{x \mid x \in \mathbb R , x^2 < 2\}$ has a least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

So we assume $b$ to be the least upper bound and we must show that $b^2 = 2$. We show that by showing that $b^2 < 2$ and $b^2> 2$ is immposible. However, I don't know how to do that. Any help please?

Comment: Once you have proven the assertion that $b$ exists (not sure what definitions or axioms you're working with here), suppose $b^{2} < 2$. Then see if you can show $b$ is not an upper bound for $S$, i.e. there is some element $s \in S$ such that $b < s$, a contradiction. Suppose $b^{2} > 2$. Then see if you can show that there exists $b'$ such that $b' < b$ but $b'$ is also an upper bound for $S$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that $1 \in S$, so $S$ is non empty.

Note that if $x \ge 0, h>0$ then $(x+h)^2 = x^2 + 2xh + h^2 > x^2$ and so $x \mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing for $x\ge0$.
We have $2^2 = 4 >2$, hence if $x \in S$, then $x^2 <2<2^2$ and so $x < 2$. Hence $2$ is an upper bound for $S$ and so using the least upper bound property we see that $S$ has a least upper bound, call it $b$. The above
comments show that $1 \le b \le 2$.

Suppose $b^2 <2$. Choose $h = {2 -b^2 \over 5}$. Then
$b+h >b$ and $(b+h)^2 = b^2+2bh+h^2 < b^2+5h =2$,
and so $b+h \in S$ which contradicts $b$ being an upper bound.

Suppose $b^2 >2$. Choose $h = {b^2-2 \over 2b}$.
Then $(b-h)^2 = b^2-2bh+h^2 > b^2-2bh =2$. Hence if $x \in S$, we have
$x^2 <2 < (b-h)^2$ and so $x < b-h$ (use injectivity of $x \mapsto x^2$ here).
Hence $b-h$ is an upper bound for $S$ and is strictly less than $b$ which
contradicts the definition.

Comment: Why can't we just check the criterions for LUB? (bounded, nonempty, and subset of $\Bbb R$)

Comment: I rewrote the answer.